# rpm: Contradictory information (both installed and not installed)

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

`rpm` (on RedHat EL 6) is giving me contradictory information:

```
[root@aphrodite Desktop]# rpm -e DeepFlow-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
error: package DeepFlow-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
[root@aphrodite Desktop]# rpm -i DeepFlow-1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
package DeepFlow-1.0-1.el6.x86_64 is already installed
```

How can my package be both installed and not installed? How can I clean up this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rpm -e expects package name as argument, not the whole rpm file. try this:

```
 rpm -e DeepFlow
```

or

```
 rpm -e DeepFlow-1.0
```

depending on whats registered as package name in the rpm db, one of them should work.